# Does every OWCA agent have a separate Major or official that they receive orders from?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

We know that Perry the Platypus - Agent P. - from *Phineas and Ferb* gets orders from Major Francis Monogram and Carl the intern. But when we get a view from Pinky the Chihuahua - Agent P. - we see that he receives orders from a different person, a woman.

Does each OWCA agent receive orders from a different authority figure or do those two also give orders to other agents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One commanding officer has multiple animal agents under them and it has been shown multiple times. Even **Major Monogram** in epilogue of episode *Traffic Cam Caper*, make a song with many of his agents:

But there are more agents than that under Monogram which we see in many episodes like [Agent W (whale)](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Agent_W_(whale)) and [Agent E](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Agent_E).

But for **Wanda Acronym** we only see her assistant Carla and Agent Pinky only. Maybe she have more agents which we never got to know about.

Even there are agents like [Peter the Panda](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_the_Panda) which seem to be from different divisions and reporting neither to  Wanda nor to Monogram.

Refer [this wikia](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_O.W.C.A._agents) for more details.